# FCM - Can I create a topic from group of topics?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create a topic say `group 11 (1-5)`, `group 12 (6-10)`, `group 13 (11-15)` and so on.
And then again a new topic `group 21(1-10)`, `group 22(11-20)`, `group 23(21-30)` and so on.

Is there any way I can do this by just grouping the first created topics?

For ex - `group 11` & `group 12` can be merged to form group 21.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a topic that is a grouping of other topics.

But you can [subscribe a client to multiple topics in one go with a condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#build_send_requests).For example:

```
'group 11' in topics || 'topic 1' in topics
```

This would subscribe the client to both `topic 1` and `group 11`, which you marked as the group you want the topic to be in. If you do the same for clients that subscribe to other topics in that group, you can either send a message to a specific topic or to the "group topic" to reach these clients.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in these operators, the problem is that I cannot use it on more than 5 operands. It would be very helpful if I can use 20 operands with the above operators.

Comment: In that case unfortunately there is no solution. There is no way to create a topic that is a grouping of other topics.